# How to code an windows 10 UI (C#) for notification zone ? (Example below)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I recently upgrade to windows and of course some of my GUI have change.
For instance :

[image]

this appears when I click on batery icon.

Is this possible to use this UI to code an app?

Comment: You can make applications that notify for sure.  But thats an incredibly open ended question.

Comment: I meant  Is there a component specificly to do that ?

Comment: There is a notifyicon but the display portion you need to make yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the code for "Ear Trumpet" which has a UI that's shown by the notification tray. It's open source on [GitHub](https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet)

Comment: but without 3rd-party  component ?

Comment: You could do something with custom coloring of the TitleBar, like so: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/easily-manage-the-title-bar-in-windows-10-apps/

Comment: And can I show a panel when i click on notifyIcon ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. UWP apps focus more on the action center and the new toast notifications

Comment: EarTrumpet dev here -- You may want to look at our interop with the OS https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet/blob/master/EarTrumpet/Extensions/BlurWindowExtensions.cs